# Como agregar css y js a codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Mi código:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('/resourse/rs-plugin/css/settings.css');?>" media="screen" />
```

Pero obtengo el error:

```
GET http://mi_ip/mi_web/resourse/rs-plugin/css/settings.css 404 (Not Found)
```

Cuando intento ingresar directamente al archivo me sale el error:

> 404 Page Not Found

Todos los archivos y las rutas existen pero no los encuentra...

¿Que me falta? gracias!

Comment: tal vez los pasos que se indican aquí te sean de utilidad https://wlannot.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/estilos-css-en-codeigniter/

Comment: solo cambie el nombre de resourse a assets y ya funciona O_O

Comment: que bueno te sirvió @Alf lo que hiciste

Comment: Una cosa ¿Dónde tienes la carpeta assets? Quiero saber por que me pasa lo mismo, no me lo encuentra.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que cambiar base_url por site_url, te quedaria algo asi

```
<?php echo site_url('/resourse/rs-plugin/css/settings.css');?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modifica la variable "base_url" en el archivo application/config/config.php con la url de tu web:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.miweb.com/carpeta';
```

Answer (score 0):

para agregar tus archivos css debes realizar el link de esta forma:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=base_url('resources/rs-plugin/css/settings.css')?>">
```

y para los archivos js:

```
<script src="<?=base_url('resources/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>
```

Si te das cuenta a comparación de como lo tienes, aquí no se utiliza el `php echo`